# Assign association without record being reloaded

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, stub

When I try to assign a Cart to the associated Order, Order will freshly load that cart again from the database, and my stubbing to cart is lost.

(Order belongs_to cart)

```
cart = create(:cart)
allow(cart).to receive(:total){ Money.new(100,'USD') }
subject.cart = cart
# subject.cart.total != Money.new(100,'USD') because that cart is not stubbed
```

What is the best way to test around this?

I can't just stub out the association like the following because some callback will not be called:

```
subject.stub(:cart){ cart } # does not apply to me
```

Comment: Have you tried to stub assigned cart (`allow(subject.cart).to ...`)?

Answer (score 0):

Since I have a special requirement that I cannot simple stub association accessor methods, I resort to using fixtures. Basically I create a valid set of record associated with each other, and test using those.